# Symfony upgrade to 4.1 assets error

Tags: symfony, assets, symfony4, symfony-3.3, symfony-3.4

I migrated a project for Symfony 4.1 but did not change the file structure to new Symfony files structure. My assets, for example, remain in the \web folder.
It works fine except for assets. To fix this problem I replaced in the controllers:

```
$this->container->get('templating.helper.assets')->getUrl($path);
```

to

```
$this->container->get('assets.packages')->getUrl($path);
```

I also execute the following command: **composer require symfony/asset**

After this, when I run the web page I am getting the following error:

*The "assets.packages" service or alias has been removed or inlined when the container was compiled. You should either make it public, or stop using the container directly and use dependency injection instead.*

To try to fix this error, I put it in services.yml:

```
services:
assets.packages:
    class: \Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages
    public: true
```

But after that I get another error:

[image]

Do you have any idea what that might be? Is something wrong?

Comment: Your `services.yml` is not well indented, is it a typo ?

Comment: Yes, the yml is valid. The error I get is **"There is no default asset package, configure one first."**

Comment: The yml is _valid_ but **not correctly indented**. There should be 4 spaces before `assets.package` if you want it to be a child of `services`

Comment: Yes and have all 4 spaces! It was just a typo here. Is there a way to configure the default package I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been able to fix  the error. It was enough to add as argument in the service the default package:

```
assets.packages:
    class: \Symfony\Component\Asset\Packages
    arguments: ['@assets._default_package']
    public: true
```

Comment: You can explain why you need an argument, and not try globally to add new packages

Answer (score 0):

Assetic is no longer used, please use Webpack Encore https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend.html